# Image path from S3 to pytorch script for Sagemaker train

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am building a AWS Pipeline to train a PyTorch model using Sagemaker. I have specified the s3 bucket (data/training)in Yaml file.

I usually upload a csv file in keras using,

`dataframe = pd.read_csv(paths.input(channel='training', filename="ab.csv"))`

In pytorch I am trying to use S3 bucket to get images in folders (labels as folder name and images inside the folder).

for the local compilation, the path is written as

`datasource = "xyz/data/"`

`tr_data = ImageFolder(datasource, transform=tr_tf)` in the working directory.

for using in sagemaker tha python bundle is specified as

`datasource =  paths.input(channel='training')` but AWS Sage-maker job fails.

Would be grateful if anyone help me to give a path of training images in S3 bucket.